# Visual Studio 2015, Nuget and “same key has already been added.”

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, nuget, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I have Visual Studio 2015 RC. When I open a console app or a Windows Phone 8 Silverlight project, everything works fine, I can use Nuget without problems.

When I open a Universal App project (Windows 8.1 + Windows Phone 8.1), Nuget breaks. When I open the Nuget console, I see

[image]

When I try to install a Nuget package using the Nuget GUI, I get the same error.

One more strange thing. When I open VS2015 RC without any projects and open the Nuget console, I do not get the error. Then when I open my Universal App project, the error appears.

I am pretty sure it is connected to the Universal App project.

I testes the Universal App project in VS2013 and everything works fine there, no problems with Nuget.

I tried all the steps in [installing nuget package "same key has already been added."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429838/installing-nuget-package-same-key-has-already-been-added) but it did not help. I guess it is because another folder may be corrupted in my case.

Happens to me on two separate machines, both run Windows 8.1 Pro, one has only VS2015 RC and on has both VS2013 Pro and VS2015 Pro.

Comment: Do you have the latest nuget installed? I'm currently working on VS2015 RC with universal apps and I didn't get this error... but i updated the Nuget add on as soon as I got VS2015 RC installed.

Comment: yes, everything is up to date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same problem with VS2013 from time to time.  While I don't have the exact steps to resolve here, the following summarizes what worked (it may be over kill).

1. use the package manager to remove all packages
2. remove the library binding section in the app config
3. re-add the packages via the package manager

It is a windows machine, you may need to restart visual studio between each step.

Comment: What do you mean by step 2? There is no app.config windows or windows phone project or PCLs

Comment: @IgorKulman glad this worked for you.  I haven't needed to perform this since the first time (3 - 4 months ago).  It was a pain in the ___ but the issue has not returned.

Comment: yes, real pain, my Nuget was so broken it could not even remove packages so I had to manually delete all package.config files and remove references from all projects

Comment: after that i stopped using the nuget UI and stuck to the power shell `Package Manager Console`.