# nuget fails to install, update or remove packages "same key has already been added."

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015

I can't install/upgrade/uninstall any nuget packages on one of our solutions. It's not to do with the PCL from what I can tell as it's the same on two machines. One of the three projects in the solution can be updated with nuget, the other two (larger projects) fail with the stacktrace below.

Has anyone seen this or know how to resolve it? We don't have duplicate package names in the packages.config, clearing them, the folder and references doesn't help, we're running in Admin mode and nuget it up to date.

Although similar to these [1], [2] and [3], the stack trace doesn't match and none of the fixes work.

[1] [Visual Studio 2015, Nuget and “same key has already been added.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399615/visual-studio-2015-nuget-and-same-key-has-already-been-added)

[2] [An item with the same key has already been added while Installing nuget package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406071/an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added-while-installing-nuget-package)

[3] [installing nuget package "same key has already been added."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429838/installing-nuget-package-same-key-has-already-been-added)

```
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'jQuery.1.11.3' with respect to project 'www', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'
    Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'jQuery.1.11.3' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
    Resolving actions to install package 'jQuery.1.11.3'
    Resolved actions to install package 'jQuery.1.11.3'
    Removed package 'jQuery.1.6.4' from 'packages.config'
    Executing script file 'xxx\projectName\packages\jQuery.1.6.4\Tools\uninstall.ps1'...
    Successfully uninstalled 'jQuery.1.6.4' from www
    Adding package 'jQuery.1.11.3' to folder 'xxx\projectName\packages'
    Added package 'jQuery.1.11.3' to folder 'xxx\projectName\packages'
    Added package 'jQuery.1.11.3' to 'packages.config'
    Executing script file 'xxx\projectName\packages\jQuery.1.11.3\tools\install.ps1'...
    True


    IsDirty              : False
    FileCount            : 1
    Name                 : jquery-1.11.3.intellisense.js
    Collection           : System.__ComObject
    Properties           : System.__ComObject
    DTE                  : System.__ComObject
    Kind                 : {6BB5F8EE-4483-11D3-8BCF-00C04F8EC28C}
    ProjectItems         : System.__ComObject
    Object               : System.__ComObject
    ExtenderNames        : {}
    ExtenderCATID        : {610D4615-D0D5-11D2-8599-006097C68E81}
    Saved                : True
    ConfigurationManager : 
    FileCodeModel        : 
    Document             : 
    SubProject           : 
    ContainingProject    : System.__ComObject



    Successfully installed 'jQuery 1.11.3' to www
    Install failed. Rolling back...
    Removed package 'jQuery 1.11.3' from 'packages.config'
    Executing script file 'xxx\projectName\packages\jQuery.1.11.3\Tools\uninstall.ps1'...
    True
    Package 'jQuery.1.6.4' already exists in folder 'xxx\projectName\packages'
    Added package 'jQuery.1.6.4' to 'packages.config'
    Executing script file 'xxx\projectName\packages\jQuery.1.6.4\Tools\install.ps1'...
    Removing package 'jQuery 1.11.3' from folder 'xxx\projectName\packages'
    Removed package 'jQuery 1.11.3' from folder 'xxx\projectName\packages'
    System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
       at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.BindingRedirectResolver.GetBindingRedirects(IEnumerable`1 assemblies)
       at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.BindingRedirectResolver.GetBindingRedirects(IEnumerable`1 assemblyPaths, AppDomain domain)
       at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.RuntimeHelpers.<AddBindingRedirectsAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.RuntimeHelpers.<AddBindingRedirectsAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.RuntimeHelpers.<AddBindingRedirectsAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.VSMSBuildNuGetProjectSystem.<<AddBindingRedirects>b__59_0>d.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
       at NuGet.PackageManagement.VisualStudio.VSMSBuildNuGetProjectSystem.AddBindingRedirects()
       at NuGet.ProjectManagement.MSBuildNuGetProject.PostProcessAsync(INuGetProjectContext nuGetProjectContext, CancellationToken token)
       at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__42.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__42.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<ExecuteActionsAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<PerformActionAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
    ========== Finished ==========
```

Comment: Digging further, I've found that this also causes the issue (I suspect this is the underlying command getting run) `Get-Project –All | Add-BindingRedirect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help out anyone else having this issue, I found it was caused because we had dependentAssembly that didn't have a bindingRedirect in our web.config (this happens when using uCommerce to redirect their dll references) e.g.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Infralution.Licensing" publicKeyToken="3e7e8e3744a5c13f" />
    <codeBase version="4.7.1.0" href="bin\ucommerce\Infralution.Licensing.dll" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I've checked the nuget change log and there's a [similar thing reported here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1142) so will wait for the latest release and see if that resolves it.

It also appears to have an issue with an alias'd reference which I'll report