# Installing Nuget package throws "An item with the same key has already been added" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget

I have an MVC3 application which has a mixture of directly referenced binaries with paths such as:

C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\app\AppNamespace\bin\ActionMailer.Net.dll

and binaries installed via NuGet like this:

C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\app\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.1\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

> I am trying to get the app to build only using NuGet so  we don't have to move dlls into remote repositories

**Taking ActionMailer as an example, here is what I am doing**

- verify the package isn't installed in the NuGet Package Manager
- remove the reference to ActionMailer.Net
- install the package via Package Manager Console which throws the following error:

  Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'ActionMailer.0.7.4' with respect to project 'NameSpace', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5' Install-Package : **An item with the same key has already been added.**
- [This Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24429838/3213157) suggested finding what the stacktrace shows:

`"$error[0].exception.stacktrace" An item with the same key has already been added. Unable to find type [T4Scaffolding.ScaffolderAttribute].[0].exception.stacktrace`

- I have tried looking up the `T4Scaffolding.ScaffolderAttribute` error but I haven't been able to find a solution

Comment: Have you verified that ActionMailer is not under the Installed Packages before attempting to install it via package manager console?

Comment: Yes, I have checked and the package isn't installed - will update my post