# Confusion over NuGet in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

Our VS2013 solutions contain a solution folder called `.nuget`, containing the files NuGet.config, NuGet.exe, NuGet.targets. What is the significance of this folder and what uses the files? Is it related to the "enable package restore" feature?

If I install or update a package (via the "Manage NuGet Packages" UI or package manager console), does this involve running the above NuGet.exe, or something else? VS is telling me that the NuGet Package Manager is up to date (via the Extensions and Updates dialog), however the above NuGet.exe is quite old. I've also found a very old NuGet.exe file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\`. What uses the latter, and what are the implications of these exes being out of date?

The reason I ask is that we've been having problems with a couple of solutions over recent weeks. We can't update NuGet packages - the operation fails with the message "Error: An item with the same key has already been added". I'm trying to track down the cause, and wondering if these out of date NuGet.exe files might have something to do with it.

Comment: There is a [*much* better question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24429838/17034) that documents this error.  That's how you ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember this folder is useless now with the latest nuget extension to Visual Studio. It was used before and was nothing but pain in the ass. I am not 100% sure about 2013, but in 2015 all works fine without it, so my suggestion is to update to the latest available nuget extension version and try to delete the folder, most likely everything will work.

Now packages go to current user folder, and use the config from `%AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.config`. For NuGet 2.6 or earlier, this setting was available in a project-specific `.nuget\nuget.config` file.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/package-restore).

So nuget is gradually getting better and easy to use without too much thinking of all this "magic" folders and stuff.